# adding 200 routes with busybox

Tags: linux, routes, busybox

I need to add 200 routes using /sbin/route when my linux is switching ip familly.

My problem is adding or deleting 200 routes takes many times on my board and I need to find a way to do it quicker.

Is there a way to add a group of routes ? or do I need to customize the /sbin/route app ?

I need help :)

Comment: Do you really need these 200 routes ?

Comment: It should be possible to add all these routes beforehand to a separate *table* ([policy routing](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.html)). When switching, just activate that *table* by adding a specific *rule* and deactivate the other one with the routes you don't want anymore by removing the corresponding *rule*. But I don't know if busybox' `route` supports *policy routing*.

Comment: @scai: The deprecated `/sbin/route` doesn't, but busybox's version of `/sbin/ip` does. However, you may have dependency problems if you want to add an indirect route with a gateway that is not currently routable by the kernel.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Yes I need all these routes. I don't have /sbin/ip on my board, I have to check if I can add it easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way.

it was the spawn time from my bash which was taking time.
so i added my 100 routes whith 1 call of `bash -c`.

It results by a gain of 200% of time.